# Repairing Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia

So I recently installed Ubuntu onto my laptop and everything was working fine except for one thing I noticed that my games were running brutally slow, so I asked my friend for advice and he suggested I use this line of code

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

in terminal to update my Nvidia Graphics card drivers. So I installed that and then noticed that **my games and Blender wouldn't even launch any more**, they would for about a second and then just close. So I used this code

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

to uninstall the Nvidia driver update my friend suggested. After that I tried multiple other Nvidia driver updates people suggested online but non of them has fixed the problem.

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the end problem is. Are your games still not opening or are they just back to running slow? What do you want us to help fix?

Comment: I would to at least like be able to fix the problem of not even being able to launch my games, I will deal with the other problem another time. Also thank for pointing out the fact the my question was incoherent.